# Three.js Dragcontrols move object from camera to scene

Tags: three.js

I have an cube set as child to the `camera`, so that when you move the camera (using `OrbitControls`) the cube is in a fixed position (moves with the camera)

When dragging the cube using `DragControls` I want to transfer the cube from the `camera` into the `scene`, so that instead of moving with the camera, the cube is a normal object with no parent and just sits in the 3D scene.

The problem is that in `DragControls` when you mousedown the `_offset` of the cube gets set before the `dragstart` event: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/DragControls.js#L159

So when I listen to the `dragstart` and then move the cube from `camera` to `scene` parent, then set the new position and `updateMatrixWorld()` it has no affect seeing as DragControls is remembering the old position/matrix when the click first occurred.

Here is my `dragstart` listener:

```
dragControls.addEventListener( 'dragstart', function (event) {
        orbitControls.enabled = false;

        if(event.object.parent.type === "OrthographicCamera") {
            scene.attach(event.object);
            event.object.position.set(5, 0, 0);
            event.object.updateMatrixWorld();
        }

    } );
```

The current code works when you initial click the cube, but as soon as you move it (and the `drag` occurs the initial _offset causes the cube to ping back into an odd position.

Is there any way I can do this or would I need to modifier the DragControls module itself?